# Measure defined on an intersection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and let $X_n\subset X, n\geq1$. Let $m_n$ be a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\{X_n\cap Y:Y\in\Sigma\}$. How to prove that $$m:\Sigma\to[0,\infty], \quad m(A)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty m_n(A\cap X_n)$$ is a measure?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show that $m_n(\cdot \cap X_n)$ are measures for $n=1,\ldots,\infty$. Then show that an infinite sum of measures is a measure.

Comment: @Jonas Do I have to show that $m_n(A\cap X_n)$ are measures on $\Sigma$? I.e. in order for the sum of $m_n$-s to be a measure on $\Sigma$ they all have to be measures on $\Sigma$? And it's not enough that $m_n$-s are measures on $\{X_n\cap Y:Y\in\Sigma\}$?

Comment: Exactly, it is not enough to consider the trace $\sigma$-algebras $\{X_n \cap Y : Y \in \Sigma\}$. But that is actually not too difficult. Maybe think about conditional probabilities - if that helps you.